# Why we learn Bavli instead of Yerushalmi

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag

If I were to learn Talmud Bavli Brachos or Talmud Yerushalmi Brachos, which one should I start with and why? Seemingly, I should start with Yerushalmi first because it came before the Bavli, but on the other hand (supposedly) we don't involve ourselves to much in the Yersushalmi at all as a whole. The question looking for an answer from an established reliable source.

Comment: Tradition... Learning is a tradition. The tradition is to learn bavli and Rashi and Tosfot as naturally as you wear tefillin

Comment: @kouty and then according to "tradition" when does one learn Yerushalmi?

Comment: Without knowing what your goal is, it's impossible for someone to recommend which one to learn first.

Comment: Halacha kbasrai,the Yerushalmi is not an easy limmud since its written in a terse fashion.

Comment: While I voted to reopen, I agree you should rewrite the question in a general form - why Bavli if better than Yerushalmi so everyone is busy studying it instead of the later?